# Hilbert scheme construction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$f:\Bbb{P}^r\times G \to G$ where $G =G(q(n),H^0(\Bbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))$ is grasmannian.($q(t)$ is fixed polynomial).
by base change theorem we can see that $f_\ast \mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r\times G}(n)= H^0(\Bbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))\otimes \mathcal{O}_G$.

Let $F$ be the universal sheaf on $G$

1) what do we mean by $H^0(\Bbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))\otimes \mathcal{O}_G$? Do we consider $H^0(\Bbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))$ as a constant sheaf on $G$?

Comment: Did you mean $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n\times G}(n)$ in the second line?

Comment: yes,thank you...

Comment: Then it is just Kunneth formula, the tensor product is over the base field.

Comment: actually my question is: what is the meaning of this tensor product.Here we tensor$H^0(\Bbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))$ with structure sheaf of garassmannian i want to know what does $H^0(\Bbb{P}^r,\mathcal{O}_\Bbb{P^r}(n))$ mean here.I didnt mean how to prove it.Thanks

Comment: It is just a vector space over the base field. So, when you tensor with the structure sheaf, you get a trivial vector bundle of rank equal to the the dimension of this vector space over $G$.